# How to use a string variable in path?

Tags: c#

How can I use a string variable in a system path? Here is sample the C# code:

```
  public class Test
   {
   public Item Met()
    {
     string file_name = "sample1.pdf";
     ///I' m just giving the code where I have the problem, not full code
     /// kindly ignore the syntax errors if any
     FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("c:\\Temp\\sample1.pdf"); 

      //   Here I tried "C:\\Temp\\" + file_name   //

    string requestBodyStart = "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" +
                   "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n" +
                   "Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n" +
                "\r\n" +
                envDef + "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" +       
                "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n" +
                "Content-Disposition: file;filename=\"sample2.pdf\";  documentId=1\r\n" +         
                    "\r\n"; ///Here in place of "sample.pdf" I want to use variable name

            string requestBodyEnd = "\r\n--BOUNDARY--\r\n\r\n";
```

At the second case I tried `"Content-Disposition: file;file_name=\" + file_name +\"` 
But I' m getting this:

> Unrecognized escape sequence, Unexpected character '\'

Is this the correct way of using variable in a path?

Thank you.

Comment: Try formatting your question's code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx) method to concatenate two string paths.

```
string file_name = "sample1.pdf";
FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine("c:\\Temp", file_name);
```

also consider [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement since `FileStream` implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 2):

You forget two `"`s in your statement

```
"Content-Disposition: file;filename=\"" + file_name + "\";  documentId=1\r\n" +
```

But I would prefer `String.Format`

```
String.Format("Content-Disposition: file;filename=\"{0}\";  documentId=1\r\n", file_name) +
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`Path.Combine Method (String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) method.

> Combines two strings into a path.

Answer (score 0):

better you create download link for read a file.

.aspx :

```
<asp:Panel ID="AttachmentPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
<asp:HyperLink ID="DownloadHyperLink" runat="server" Text="Download Attachment"</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Panel>
```

.cs :

```
string file_name = "http://192.168.100.1:400/sample1.pdf";
this.DownloadHyperLink.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "window.open('" + file_name + "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new versions, you can use `String.Format()` function and the'`@`' special character serves as verbatim identifier. An example of use:

You want to open a file in `C:/Users/YourUser/Desktop/Documents/`, and have the user select the document from a drop-down list. To create the string, you could do something:

```
string filePath = String.Format(@"C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\Documents\{0}", selectedFile);
```

You can read the [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) for more information and examples.

Greetings.

Answer (score -2):

Replace '\' with '\\' in your string path

Comment: '\' with '\' ? what is the difference?